# How to use reg-ex group matching in javascript (Python equivalent)?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ecmascript-5

```
import re
items = ["abc","def","a123","bgh5"]
ele_list = ["dsdsd-vfvfv-abc.xyz.com", "lbebbe-fjhdhf-abc.xyz.com", "bdfhjd-bjsbjd-bgh5.lmn.com"]
pattern = "(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.\w+\.com"
test_data = {}
for item in items:
    tmp_data = [i for i in ele_list if re.search(pattern, i).group(3) == item.lower()]
    test_data[item] = tmp_data
    
print(test_data)
```

Above snippet groups each pattern (3rd group) and assigns that respective key as a value.

```
{
    'abc': ['dsdsd-vfvfv-abc.xyz.com', 'lbebbe-fjhdhf-abc.xyz.com'],
    'def': [],
    'a123': [],
    'bgh5': ['bdfhjd-bjsbjd-bgh5.lmn.com']
}
```

I am trying to do the similar thing in javascript, but I am not sure if same utilities exist in javascript.

Below is my javascript version, but unable.

```
var items = ["ABC","DEF","A123","BGH5"];
var ele_list = ["dsdsd-vfvfv-abc.xyz.com", "lbebbe-fjhdhf-abc.xyz.com", "bdfhjd-bjsbjd-bgh5.lmn.com"];
var pattern = RegExp("(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.\w+\.com", "g");
var test_data = {};
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var tmp_data = ele_list.filter(function(x) {return x.match(pattern)})[3] === item.toLowerCase() ;
    test_data[i] = tmp_data;
    }
console.log(test_data);
```

Is anything wrong here ? Is there any best possible solution to convert python equivakent to javascript ? **(ecmascript5)**

Answer (score 0):

I changed it a bit, so that it gives the exact same result as the python version:

```js
const items = ["ABC","DEF","A123","BGH5"];
const ele_list = ["dsdsd-vfvfv-abc.xyz.com", "lbebbe-fjhdhf-abc.xyz.com", "bdfhjd-bjsbjd-bgh5.lmn.com"];
const pattern = /(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.\w+\.com/;
const test_data = {};
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const tmp_data = ele_list.filter(function(x) {return x.match(pattern)[3] == items[i].toLowerCase()}) ;
    test_data[items[i]] = tmp_data;
}
console.log(test_data);
```

I set the pattern to directly be a regular expression.

The strict comparison always returned false, even when the values were the same, so I changed it to `==`.

Also, you need to use the index to access the array element within the for loop. Like `items[i]`.

If you want to use the element value as the key for the object, then you have to do it like `test_data[items[i]]`. If you want the keys to be lower case, then you can use `test_data[items[i].toLowerCase()]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I really appreciate it. 
strict comparison doesn't work ?